# What does 2*f mean in c? What is this function supposed to output?

Tags: c, floating-point

I am not asking for an answer, but I have no idea what the professor means when he is asking us to solve this function:

[image]

What does 2*f mean? What is the function supposed to do after taking a floating point?

Comment: I suppose that your professor wants you to hack the mantissa to shift it so it multiplies the float value by 2.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre ah, so basically just shifting the mantissa would be like multiplying by two because each bit moving would be shifting up a power?

Comment: Multiplication by a power of two only changes the signficand for subnormal numbers. For most numbers, you only need to change the exponent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is using `*` to mean multiplication. He's asking you to take an unsigned input and produce an unsigned output that has a bit representation of a floating point value with twice the value as one with the bit representation of the input.

Comment: So if I put in a floating point like 0.1525, it should return 0.305?

Comment: Yep! My sense is that the goal here is to have you implement the bit manipulations on the IEEE-754 representation necessary to perform that multiplication.